# Как найти угол между двумя направлениями в трех измерениях?

Tags: java, математика, геометрия

Есть стрелка направленная от начала координат на координаты `[1,1,1]`
Как найти горизонтальный и вертикальный угол поворота, который направит её на координаты `[1,2,3]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Узнаем нормальное направление на обе точки в плоскости XY (считаем длину вектора по XY и делим каждый компонент XY на эту длину).
2. Используя тригонометрические функции, определяем угол каждого вектора - например:

   ```
   // Convert XY to euler value
   Angle := ArcTan2(-X, Y) / Pi * 180;
   ```
3. Считаем разницу между углами
4. Повторяем то же для плоскости YZ или XZ (на ваш выбор).